# Acumatica REST API Error: Inter-Branch Transactions feature is disabled

Tags: acumatica

We are using the REST API to create a Sales Order in Acumatica. For some customers we receive the below error message. Not sure why the API is complaining about “inter branch” as we target a single tenant and try to create a sales order for an existing customer under that tenant. (Not sure if branch means something else than “tenant” in this context)

I read the other post on the forum and tried to find the feature for enabling inter branch but that feature was not listed. Can someone please help with this?

Exception: An error occurred during processing of the field Allocated value False Inter-Branch Transactions feature is disabled.
PX.Data.PXOuterException: An error occurred during processing of the field Allocated value False Inter-Branch Transactions feature is disabled

We do not pass a field called “Allocated” and not sure why the API is complaining about it.

Below is a sample request we pass and it only happens for some customers and not all:

{"CustomerID":{"value":"C006089"},"Description":{"value":"Hinnershitz"},"Details":[{"InventoryID":{"value":"DESIGNER"},"LineDescription":{"value":"Kitchen - perimeter - Hampton (Pure White), Frameless, Birch Plywood, Dovetailed Wood\n"},"OrderQty":{"value":1},"UnitPrice":{"value":7105.059800000001}},{"InventoryID":{"value":"FUEL SURCHARGE"},"OrderQty":{"value":1},"UnitPrice":{"value":355.25299000000007}}]}

Comment: Do you have multiple companies/branches in your tenant? Usually, this error happens when you create an order in the company/branch A using a warehouse associated with the company/branch B, which means that the items will be shipped out from the warehouse of the company/branch B, but the company/branch A is the actual selling company/branch. In that case, Acumatica tries to create due to/from transaction in GL to properly apply the COGS

Answer (score 0):

You must enable Inter-Branch transactions feature.
[image]

Comment: I do not see this on our install - do we need to call Acumatica to enable it?